# C# Downcasting with generics

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, generics, casting

In our project we are using .net WPF with MEF and prism.
I have to do some task and as a part of it I have different classes of Model, all implementing IModel interface (let's call them Model1, Model2, Model3).
For each model class I need to create a view model (ViewModel1, ViewModel2, ViewModel3).
I would like to do it in some generic way so it will be extensible and if tomorrow someone will implement IModel in different dll that I doesn't know about, I still will be able to create a view model for it.

I though about something like this:

```
    [InheritedExport]
public interface IViewModelFactory<T>
{
    IViewModel Create(string id, IEnumerable<IModel> modelsList);
}

public class ViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory<Model1>
{
    public IViewModel Create(string id, IEnumerable<IModel> modelsList)
    {
        return new ViewModel1(targetId, modelsList);;
    }
}

public class FactoryLocator
{
    public static IViewModelFactory<T> GetFactory<T>(T parameters)
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IViewModelFactory<T>>();
    }
}
```

And then I will use it that way:

```
        public void CreateAndAddVM(IList<IModel> modelsList)
    {
        var factory = FactoryLocator.GetFactory(modelsList.FirstOrDefault());
        var vm = factory.Create(_id, modelsList);
        ViewModels.Add(vm);
    }
```

When I get to the FactoryLocator, the type is actually IModel interface and not a Model1/2/3.

Is there any way to make it work somehow? Or maybe another way to implement this requirement?

Comment: type parameters are resolved compile time and at compile time your model is of type IModel which is what causes the problem for you

Comment: At this moment, anyone can create a view model with a model that may not be intended for it.

For example, if your ViewModel depends on **Model1**, there's nothing stopping me from providing a list of **Model2** to the `Create` method in your factory.

Could this be a problem?

Comment: @MikeEason Yes, now I see it.
 Maybe you can suggest another way to solve it in extensible and generic way?

Comment: @RuneFS  Maybe you can suggest another way to solve it in extensible and generic way?

Answer (score 0):

You should start with interface defined like this

```
public interface IViewModelFactory<T> where T : IModel 
{
    IViewModel Create(string id, IEnumerable<T> modelsList);
}
```

and it will actually force correct typing on future implementers.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but it doesn't help - as I wrote in the question the type in the FactoryLocator is still IModel

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment. At this moment, anyone can create a view model with a model that may not be intended for it.

For example, if your ViewModel depends on Model1, there's nothing stopping me from providing a list of Model2 to the `Create` method in your factory.

Consider the following:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase<TModel> where TModel : IModel
```

The example above will allow your ViewModel to specify what Model it represents, however this goes by the assumption that a ViewModel only has one Model, which may not always be the case.

In this scenario, your `ViewModelBase` class should have an ID, and a Model property for the TModel.

*Ensure that* `IModel` *inherits from* `INotifyPropertyChanged`, *this will allow* `TModel` *to be an* `ObservableCollection`.